# Best way to implement bypass circuitry for analog crossover filter circuit?

Tags: switches, audio, filter, differential-amplifier, dpdt

Below is a system block diagram of a schematic / PCB I am working on. It is an SOC with two differential audio DACs (left and right audio channel). Each channel has a fully differential cross-over filter, with the high-pass filtered outputs going to mono amplifiers and the low-pass filtered outputs going to a stereo class-D amp.

[image]

I would like to implement some circuitry to bypass the cross-over, so that all of the amps can optionally receive full bandwidth audio. I am thinking that I can use 4 DPDT switches to re-route the amplifiers' input stages to the SOC's DAC outputs rather than the crossover outputs. Below is a block diagram of my idea.

[image]

I have found this [DPDT](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/256/MAX14589E-MAX14594E-277322.pdf), that seems like a good candidate. I plan on connecting the crossover outputs to the NO pins on the DPDT so that the crossover op-amps are connected to ground via the internal 500 Ω resistors when disconnected; however, that seems like it would not be very efficient, since the opamps would still be driving a 500 Ω load when disconnected from the amplifiers.

Is there any problem with terminating the crossover op-amps in that way? Also, is there a more efficient way to implement this bypass circuitry in general? These DPDTs are not cheap, so I would be open to other options.